# How to retrieve resource groups by REST API?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm automating some IBM Cloud workflows.  One of the things I need to do is retrieve a list of resource groups via the REST API similar to `bx resource groups`.  I can trace the REST call:

```
$ IBMCLOUD_TRACE=true bx resource groups
Retrieving all resource groups under account Chris Snow's Account as xxxxx...

REQUEST: [2018-09-26T06:05:52+01:00]
GET /v1/resource_groups?account_id=xxxxxx HTTP/1.1
Host: resource-manager.bluemix.net
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Language: en
Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: IBM Cloud CLI 0.10.0 / darwin
```

Are different hosts used depending on region?  If so, how can I determine which host to send the request to?  I was hoping to find the api docs for this call at https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs but I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation available at https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/ is under construction and (it seems) more and more of the APIs are added. I expect that the Resource Controller API will be added soon.

<strike>Regarding the resource controller I checked the IP addresses for the following names and they all return the same base information:</strike>

- resource-controller.bluemix.net
- resource-manager.bluemix.net
- resource-controller.ng.bluemix.net
- resource-manager.ng.bluemix.net
- resource-controller.eu-de.bluemix.net
- resource-controller.eu-gb.bluemix.net

Because resource groups are a region-independent concept I would expect it does not matter which host name to use, it is the same database (maybe replicas). Thus, how about hardcoding resource-manager.bluemix.net for now?

Comment: When I use `https://resource-controller.ng.bluemix.net` the API call returns 404.  I had to change it to `https://resource-manager.bluemix.net` for it to work :(